# Use regex java to replace a string before and after a certain character

Tags: java, regex

*My effort: I tried looking at similar questions however I cannot figure out my answer. I also tried using the web (https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) to figure this out myself, but I just cant get the right answer. Tried using `myString.replaceAll("_.+/[^.]*/", "");`*

I have a string: `String myString = "hello_AD123.mp3";`

And I want to use regex java in order to REMOVE everything after the underscore (including it) AND stopping before the (.mp3). How would I do this?

So I want the final result to be the following: `myString = "hello.mp3";`

Comment: `myString = myString.replaceFirst("_[^.]*", "");`

Comment: It does remove, I've literally just tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex did not work because it matched something that is missing from your string:

- `_` - an underscore followed with...
- `.+` - one or more any characters other than a line feed
- `/` - a literal `/` symbol
- `[^.]*` - zero or more characters other than a dot
- `/` - a literal `/`.

There are no slashes in your input string.

You can use

```
String myString = "hello_AD123.mp3";
myString = myString.replaceFirst("_.*[.]", ".");
// OR myString = myString.replaceFirst("_[^.]*", "");
System.out.println(myString);
```

See the [IDEONE Java demo](http://ideone.com/EMZywZ)

The pattern `_[^.]*` matches an underscore and then 0+ characters other than a literal dot. **In case the string has dots before `.mp3`**, `"_.*[.]"` matches `_` up to the last `.`, and needs to be replaced with a `.`.

See the [regex Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/aL3zX0/1) and [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/aL3zX0/2).

**Details**:

- `_` - matches `_`
- `[^.]*` - matches zero or more (due to `*` quantifier) characters other than (because the negated character class is used, see `[^...]`) a literal dot (as `.` inside a character class - `[...]` - is treated as a literal dot character (full stop, period).

  - **OR**
- `.*[.]` - matches 0 or more characters other than a newline up to the last literal dot (consuming the dot, thus, the replacement pattern should be `"."`).

The `.replaceFirst()` is used because we only need to perform a *single* search and replace operation. When the matching substring is matched, it is replaced with an empty string because the replacement pattern is `""`.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the regex you used one by one please? Im confused understanding why it was used like this. It works though! Thanks

Comment: OP wants to remove chars _between_ '_' and '.mp3', thus it should rather be like `myString.replaceFirst("_.*\\.mp3", "_.mp3");` or (to use matching groups) `myString.replaceFirst("(_)(.*)(\\.mp3)", "$1$3");`.

Comment: @Andy: I see what you mean. Sure, a greedy dot matching pattern can be more useful.